# Identification: Is this an 150A fuse? Or something else?

Tags: amplifier, identification, fuses

Can anyone else identify this element? What is it? Seems to have 150A stamped on the left side - is it a fuse?

[image]

Comment: I doubt it's a fuse, as the slag would not be contained, there's no fuse body.

It's much more likely a current shunt.

Comment: @JohnD First it’s a current shunt, then a fuseas the current increases.

Comment: @winny LOL, yes, you're obviously right.

Comment: It came out of a forklift - does it make sense?

Comment: Why wasn't that mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Transistor because I didnt know. `Asking for a friend`...

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a crude form of "ANL" style automotive fuse as used in (insane) audio systems and inverters.

Similar to this (from [this](http://www.derek.com.au/fuses.html) website):

[image]

It would be used in an individual fuse holder with a (typically transparent) cover on it. As it's intended only for low voltage applications, it probably does not need to meet much in the way of safety standards to be sold.

Comment: Definitely could be a crude fuse. I originally thought shunt, but hard to see what the dimensions are from the photo.  If it's similar to your example it's too small to be a 150A shunt for sure.

Comment: A 150A shunt should have 4 connections.

Comment: Also true, but I have seen crude OCP type shunts that don't have the Kelvin connections.  Whatever it is it looks very low cost, so definitely no frills :)

Comment: My vote is also on fuse. Having designed a battery charger with a 70 A maxi fuse on the output, I see how a simplification like this could spring up on the market, at least in the EU and used on the DC side where you often only need to prove your weak link fuses each time but not actually type test it, would save a lot of money.

Comment: It came out of a forklift - does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. See, [for example,](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/specialty-power-fuses/lift-truck-fuses.aspx). Low voltage high current fuses.